# merge 2 csv files having different header into one csv file having all headers

Tags: python, csv, unix

I need unix/python code to generate a file:
there are 2 csv files
File a.csv
country,name
NA,Rupa
File b.csv
region,time
home,day

I need Output file.csv as:
country,name,region,time
NA,Rupa,home,day
NA,Rupa

The code I used is

```
cat a.csv > file.csv
cat b.csv >> file.csv
```

But its not giving me the desired output
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are much neater ways to do this, but here is a quick (and dirty) one:

```py
import pandas as pd

with open('a.csv', 'r') as a, open('b.csv', 'r') as b, open('c.csv','w') as c:
  a_lst = a.readlines(); b_lst = b.readlines(); c_lst = []
  for i in range(len(a_lst)):
    c_lst.append(a_lst[i].strip() + ',' + b_lst[i].strip())
  c.write('\n'.join(c_lst))
  
df = pd.read_csv('c.csv')
new_order = df[['country','name','region','time','NA','Rupa','home','day']]
new_order.to_csv('c.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
$ cat c.csv     
country,name,region,time,NA,Rupa,home,day
a,b,e,f,c,d,g,h
aa,bb,ee,ff,cc,dd,gg,hh
```

Comment: The input records can't be hardcoded.Let me rephrase my question,I have 2 csv files, with different headers, and its dynamic, because the fields can change each day. No common field between the 2 csv files. I need a 3rd csv file with all the headers together. For example, a.csv(fields: name, country);b.csv(fields: department, school).The output file.csv (fields:name,country, department, school)

Comment: @TAN08 The script I provided does exactly that, the last three lines are just to reorder the output as I assumed you want the output in a specific order, hence, you can delete them if you want to merge two csv files only. Please note that a.csv and b.csv must have the same number of lines.

Comment: We are facing issue in there itself now, when the count is not same. Any inputs on that?

Comment: @TAN08 That's for you to decide, do you want to fill it with a certain value? or leave it empty?